# Issue while scrolling - doesn't disable scroll fully

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I am trying to recreate a behaviour that on scroll, the scroll is being disable until the animation scroll directly to the point given. Something similar to http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ (the behaviour), but I don't want to do full page scroll, rather than I want the scroll to scroll to the specific position of the website.

JS:

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){
  //Keep track of last scroll
  var lastScroll = 0;
  var scrollBlock = false;
  var myIndex = 0;
  var myPositions = [0,1000,2000,3000];


  $(window).scroll(function(event){
      console.log(scrollBlock);
      if(scrollBlock == false){
        scrollBlock = true;
        event.preventDefault();

        //Sets the current scroll position
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        //Determines up-or-down scrolling
        if (st > lastScroll){

           console.log("DOWN");
          $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: myPositions[myIndex+1]+'px'}, 2000, function(){
            console.log(myPositions[myIndex]);
            setTimeout(function(){
              console.log(st);
              lastScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
              scrollBlock = false;
             },200);
          });
           myIndex++;

        }
        else {

           console.log("UP");
          $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: myPositions[myIndex-1]+'px'}, 2000, function(){
            console.log(myPositions[myIndex]);
            setTimeout(function(){
              console.log(st);
              lastScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
              scrollBlock = false;
              //console.log(scrollBlock);
             },200);
          });
           myIndex--;
        }
        //Updates scroll position              
      }

  });
});
```

CSS:

```
body{height: 3000px; margin:0px}
.section{position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 1000px}
.section1{background: red}
.section2{background: blue}
.section3{background: green}
```

HTML

```
<div class="section section1">Section 1</div>
<div class="section section2">Section 2</div>
<div class="section section3">Section 3</div>
```

This is codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqpxf.

The script determines whether you are scrolling UP/DOWN. Once the scroll is fired, the default scroll behaviour should be stopped and body will scroll to specific section. Right now the scroll is a bit "jittery"

Would you be able to help me with that?

Thank you very much

Comment: it happens when you play crazy on your mouse scroll, but you can disable scroll check until it reaches destination using the scroll distance value

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the reply, would you be able to point me in the right direction? Sorry, but I am going round the circles here and might have missed this.

Comment: may i ask what browser are you using?

Comment: The biggest problems that I've observed were on Safari (both desktop and ipad). The example is a part of a bigger project that I am developing - http://woosports.smartnoise.co

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example that I made for another question about scrolling, here is just 2 sections, but probably can help:

http://jsfiddle.net/zB5bc/8/

I just using:

```
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Great example, thank you!
I still have a problem, when I try to scroll while the animation is being fired. It has this "jitter" effect which is causing the jumpy content. I want to disable scroll while the animate() is being fired and enable it when it finishes.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the jsfiddle, so use the mousewheel event and than use whheelDelta property to determine the direction (user scroll up/down) and also set body overflow to hidden, should work fine. Udpated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zB5bc/20/